# symfony datetype, not enough long

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

Hello as part of a student project I am asked to work on symfony. I have a small problem I created a form in which I ask for the date of birth but the "DateType" stops at 2012 I would rather a young community all the same. How to fix this problem please.

[DateType](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzpX1.png)

[DateType Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgna0.png)

Comment: You should use the [BirthdayType Field](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/birthday.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony has a [`BirthdayType`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/birthday.html) field - it's just a DateType field that specializes in handling birthdate data.

This type is essentially the same as the DateType type, but with a more appropriate default for the years option. The years option defaults to 120 years ago to the current year.